# Customise Asp.Net Core ApiAuthorizationDbContext table names

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm working with Asp.Net Core identity, and I want to change the tables names that are generated by the default ApiAuthorizationDbContext.  For the sake of argument, let's say that I want to change `AspNetRoleClaims` to be `MyRoleClaims`.

My DbContext looks like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
        : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<MyData> MyData { get; set; }
}
```

I'm aware that if I inherit directly from `IdentityDbContext` then I can specify certain entities, but I can't see a way to do that using `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`.  It appears that the only difference between the two are the following tables:

```
public DbSet<PersistedGrant> PersistedGrants { get; set; }
public DbSet<DeviceFlowCodes> DeviceFlowCodes { get; set; }
```

So, I suppose I could create my DbContext based on `IdentityDbContext`, and add these manually, but that feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel. Is there a way to specify these table names, or do I really need to build this manually from `IdentityDbContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override OnModelCreating in your ApiAuthorizationDbContext

```html
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
    }
```